# Hibernate Pagination leaves some records when using transactions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, pagination, spring-transactions

I have developed a simple hibernate pagination using `.setFirstResult(int)` and `.setMaxResults(int)` and i have ordered my select query and everything is as expected but when transactions are used some issue raises whether pagination is inside transaction or not.
The problem is for example if page size is 10 and first is number 10 , select query leaves 10 records and then start from record number 20 and it will return records number 20 to 30. what can be the cause? 
I am using java 8 , spring 4 , hibernate 5.

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0):

Try using this approach while fetching the records from hibernate Query :--

```
query.setFirstResult((pageNumber-1)*pageSize);
query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
```